# Issues in parsing yaml file in golang

Tags: go, yaml

I am looking for unmarshaling simple yaml but something is not right. Have spent enough time already. Any help please?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    yaml "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

func main() {

    raw := `
targets:
  - from: "http://localhost:8080/test1"
    timeout: "10s"
  - from: "http://localhost:8080/test2"
    timeout: "30s"
`
    type Target struct {
        from    string `yaml:"from"`
        timeout string `yaml:"timeout"`
    }
    type config struct {
        Targets []Target `yaml:"targets"`
    }

    cfg := config{}

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(raw), &cfg)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Config", cfg)
}
```

I am getting below empty o/p

```
Config {[{ } { }]}
```

Playground -> https://play.golang.org/p/LANMpq_zPP9

Comment: By the way, it would have been easier if go compiler would have given some warning in such cases.

Comment: I think you got downvotes due to the fact that this is considered kind of a basic issue. I appreciated that you had a playground link and demonstrated what you tried. This was, in my opinion, a legitimate question.

Comment: This "{YML,JSON unmarshaling doesn't work!"-question comes up 2 to 10 times a week here on SO and the answer is always the same: Export your fields! And it's not like the documentation is unclear here or the examples in the official documentation would use unexported fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to export the fields in your struct. As stated in the api-documentation:

> Struct fields are only unmarshalled **if they are exported** (have an upper case first letter), and are unmarshalled using the field name lowercased as the default key.

(https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/blob/496545a6307b/yaml.go#L88)

Changing your `Target`-struct to:

```golang
type Target struct {
    From    string `yaml:"from"`
    Timeout string `yaml:"timeout"`
}
```

should work.

Try it: https://play.golang.org/p/ZD7Jrv0QBdn

Comment: Lol, time to go thru basics again :-(