# How to write to yml files in Go

Tags: go, yaml

I am trying to write a yml file for snowfakery in go and I am very new to go so I am unfamiliar with their structs. I have been able to write my own script to do this in python but am struggling a bit more with go. I have looked at some of the other answers for how to write to a yml file in go and they helped a lot with starting but because of the different types in my specific yml I got confused

I need the yml file to look something like this

```
- snowfakery_version: 3
- object: Logistics
  count: 1
  fields:
    Product_ID:
      random_choice:
      - M14860
      - L47181
      - L47182
    Type:
      random_choice:
      - A10
      - C17
      - F16
    Air_Temperature:
      random_number:
        min: 298
        max: 300
    Tool Wear Fail:
      if:
      - choice:
          when: ${{Tool_Wear>2}}
          pick:
            random_choice:
            - 1
            - 0
      - choice:
          when: ${{Tool_Wear<2}}
          pick: 2
```

so i have tried making structs like

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
    // "os"
    // "strings"
)


// TotalSchema represents the YAML schema
type TotalSchema struct {
    snowfakery_version []string   `yaml:"snowfakery_version"`
    object             []DataItem `yaml:"objects"`
}

// DataItem represents an object type in the schema
type DataItem struct {
    Object  string          `yaml:"object"`
    Count   int             `yaml:"count"`
    Fields  LogisticsFields `yaml:"fields"`
}

// Fields represents the fields of an object type
type LogisticsFields struct {
    ProductID           RandomChoice        `yaml:"Product_ID"`
    Type                RandomChoice        `yaml:"Type"`
    ToolWear            RandomNumber        `yaml:"Tool_Wear"`
    ToolWearFail        []ChoiceCondition   `yaml:"Tool Wear Fail"`
}

type RandomNumber struct {
    Min int `yaml:"min"`
    Max int `yaml:"max"`
}

type RandomChoice struct {
    RandomChoice []string `yaml:"random_choice"`
}

type ChoiceCondition struct {
    When string `yaml:"when"`
    Pick int    `yaml:"pick"`
}
```

but whenever I try to create the struct and use it to write to a yml file

```
func main() {

    totalStructDict.snowfakery_version = []string{"3"}

    //other funciton I use to populate the rest of the struct
    logisticsHandler(4, "logistics")
    fmt.Println(totalStructDict)
    data, err := yaml.Marshal(totalStructDict)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println( data)

    err = ioutil.WriteFile("logistics.yml", data, 0)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("YAML data has been written to 'logistics.yml' file.")
```

I get a completely empty yml file. I would love any help. Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
I have been able to get most of the way with by using the interface structure and maps ie.

```
     package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
    // "os"
    // "strings"
)

// TotalSchema represents the YAML schema
type TotalSchema struct {
    Snowfakery_version int `yaml:"snowfakery_version"`
}

// DataItem represents an object type in the schema
type DataItem struct {
    Object string      `yaml:"object"`
    Count  int         `yaml:"count"`
    Fields interface{} `yaml:"fields"`
}

// Fields represents the fields of an object type
type Fields struct {
    RandomChoices []string          `yaml:"random_choices,omitempty"`
    RandomNumber  RandomNumber      `yaml:"random_number,omitempty"`
    Choice        []ChoiceArray     `yaml:"if,omitempty"`
    Random_Choice []ChoiceProbArray `yaml:"random_choice,omitempty"`
}
type RandomNumber struct {
    Min int `yaml:"min"`
    Max int `yaml:"max"`
}

type RandomChoice struct {
    RandomChoice []string `yaml:"random_choice"`
}
type ChoiceArray struct {
    Choice ChoiceCondition `yaml:"choice"`
}
type ChoiceProbArray struct {
    ChoiceProb ChoiceProbability `yaml:"choice"`
}

type ChoiceCondition struct {
    When string `yaml:"when"`
    Pick int    `yaml:"pick"`
}

type ChoiceProbability struct {
    Probability string `yaml:"probability"`
    Pick        int    `yaml:"pick"`
}

var logisticsDict []interface{}
var totalStructDict TotalSchema
var objArray []DataItem
var object DataItem

func logisticsHandler(number int, objectName string) {
    object.Count = number
    object.Object = objectName

    logisticsDict = []interface{}{
        TotalSchema{Snowfakery_version: 3},
        DataItem{
            Object: "logistics",
            Count:  4,
            Fields: map[string]interface{}{
                "Product ID": Fields{
                    RandomChoices: []string{"M14860",
                        "L47181",
                        "L47182",
                    },
                },
                "Air_Temperature": Fields{
                    RandomNumber: RandomNumber{
                        Min: 298,
                        Max: 300,
                    },
                },
                "Process_Temperature": Fields{
                    RandomNumber: RandomNumber{
                        Min: 298,
                        Max: 300,
                    },
                },
                "Heat Dissipation Fail": Fields{
                    Choice: []ChoiceArray{
                        {ChoiceCondition{
                            When: "${{(Process_Temperature - Air_Temperature)<8.6 and Rotational_Speed<1380}}",
                            Pick: 1,
                        }},
                        {ChoiceCondition{
                            When: "${{(Process_Temperature - Air_Temperature)>8.6 or Rotational_Speed>1380}}",
                            Pick: 0,
                        }},
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }

}

func main() {

    //other funciton I use to populate the rest of the struct
    logisticsHandler(4, "logistics")
    fmt.Println(logisticsDict)
    data, err := yaml.Marshal(logisticsDict)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // fmt.Println(data)

    err = ioutil.WriteFile("logistics.yml", data, 0)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("YAML data has been written to 'logistics.yml' file.")
}
```

But now whenever I run the yaml.Marshel code it is auto sorting my code. I am now wondering how to get it to stay exactly in the order that I created it in because snowfakery relies on variables to be defined in order

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67844491/11810946) should help you move forward (export the fields by changing their names to start with an upper case character - e.g. `Snowfakery_version string   \`yaml:"snowfakery_version"\``)

Comment: That definitely helped a ton ( it is now at least exporting to the yml) but i am still struggling to get the snowfakery_version and objects to show up as "arrays"

Comment: It helps if your question includes syntactically valid, runnable code. In your `main`, function, `totalStructDict` is not defined, nor is the `logisticsHandler`. You don't need to completely reproduce your code, but there should be enough for us to run without modification to reproduce the problem you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `snowfakery_version` is the only key in a  dictionary whose value is the scalar integer value `3`. This dictionary is the first item in a list:

```
- snowfakery_version: 3
```

The JSON equivalent to the above is:

```
[
  {"snowfakery_version": 3}
]
```

That doesn't match your data structure, which looks like:

```
type TotalSchema struct {
  snowfakery_version []string   `yaml:"snowfakery_version"`
  object             []DataItem `yaml:"objects"`
}
```

This would correspond to a YAML file that looks like:

```
snowfakery_version: [3]
```

Or as JSON:

```
{
  "snowfakery_version": [3]
}
```

---

With the understanding that you're parsing an [established format](https://snowfakery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I think it's going to be a bit of pain to parse this into Go structs:

1. There does not appear to be a formal schema document
2. It looks like some of the fields are effectively "union" types. That is:

   - A field definition can either be a structure, or it can be a list of additional objects.
   - `pick` can be a scalar value (integer, string) or structure

   etc.

In go, parsing a union type usually means using an `interface{}` and then figuring out what to do dynamically by inspecting the data at runtime.

Starting at the top, your file format is a list of "things", where each thing can be either a `snowfakery_version` or an object definition. So that means we start with:

```
type SnowfakeryConfig []interface{}
```

Then we create the `struct` definitions for various types that we expect, e.g.:

```
SnowfakeryVersion struct {
  SnowfakeryVersion int `yaml:"snowfakery_version"`
}

ObjectSpec struct {
  Object string                 `yaml:"object,omitempty"`
  Count  int                    `yaml:"count,omitempty"`
  Fields map[string]interface{} `yaml:"fields,omitempty"`
}

.
.
.
```

These can be appended to a `SnowfakeryConfig` list. Here's an example that programatically produces the sample config from your question:

```
package main

import (
  "os"

  "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

type (
  SnowfakeryConfig []interface{}

  SnowfakeryVersion struct {
    SnowfakeryVersion int `yaml:"snowfakery_version"`
  }

  ObjectSpec struct {
    Object string                 `yaml:"object,omitempty"`
    Count  int                    `yaml:"count,omitempty"`
    Fields map[string]interface{} `yaml:"fields,omitempty"`
  }

  FieldSpec struct {
    Fake         string        `yaml:"fake,omitempty"`
    RandomChoice RandomChoice  `yaml:"random_choice,omitempty"`
    RandomNumber *RandomNumber `yaml:"random_number,omitempty"`
    IfExpression IfExpression  `yaml:"if,omitempty"`
    Object       string        `yaml:"object,omitempty"`
  }

  RandomChoice []interface{}
  RandomNumber struct {
    Min int
    Max int
  }

  IfExpression []Choice

  Choice struct {
    Choice ChoiceSpec
  }

  ChoiceSpec struct {
    When string
    Pick interface{}
  }
)

func main() {
  config := SnowfakeryConfig{}

  config = append(config, SnowfakeryVersion{SnowfakeryVersion: 3})

  config = append(config, ObjectSpec{
    Object: "Logistics",
    Count:  1,
    Fields: map[string]interface{}{
      "Product_ID": FieldSpec{
        RandomChoice: RandomChoice{
          "M14860",
          "L47181",
          "L47182",
        },
      },
      "Type": FieldSpec{
        RandomChoice: RandomChoice{
          "A10",
          "C17",
          "F16",
        },
      },
      "Air_Temperature": FieldSpec{
        RandomNumber: &RandomNumber{
          Min: 298,
          Max: 300,
        },
      },
      "Tool Wear Fail": FieldSpec{
        IfExpression: IfExpression{
          Choice{
            Choice: ChoiceSpec{
              When: "${{Tool_Wear>2}}",
              Pick: FieldSpec{
                RandomChoice: RandomChoice{
                  1,
                  0,
                },
              },
            },
          },
          Choice{
            Choice: ChoiceSpec{
              When: "${{Tool_Wear<2}}",
              Pick: 2,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  })

  content, err := yaml.Marshal(config)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  if err := os.WriteFile("output.yaml", content, 0666); err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

}
```

Running the above code produces, in `output.yaml`:

```
- snowfakery_version: 3
- object: Logistics
  count: 1
  fields:
    Air_Temperature:
        random_number:
            min: 298
            max: 300
    Product_ID:
        random_choice:
            - M14860
            - L47181
            - L47182
    Tool Wear Fail:
        if:
            - choice:
                when: ${{Tool_Wear>2}}
                pick:
                    random_choice:
                        - 1
                        - 0
            - choice:
                when: ${{Tool_Wear<2}}
                pick: 2
    Type:
        random_choice:
            - A10
            - C17
            - F16
```

---

Parsing the YAML requires us to dynamically detect object types at runtime. We can do this by looking for specific keys in each item read from the file:

```
fd, err := os.ReadFile("sample.yaml")
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

if err := yaml.Unmarshal(fd, &config); err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

for _, item := range config {
  if _, ok := item.(map[string]interface{})["snowfakery_version"]; ok {
    fmt.Println("found version")
    if err := mapstructure.Decode(item, &version); err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("version: %d\n", version.SnowfakeryVersion)
    continue
  }
  if _, ok := item.(map[string]interface{})["object"]; ok {
    fmt.Println("found object")
    if err := mapstructure.Decode(item, &objspec); err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("object name: %s\n", objspec.Object)
    for k := range objspec.Fields {
      fmt.Printf("  field: %s\n", k)
    }
    continue
  }
}
```

In this example I'm using the [`mapstructure`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure) module to convert our `map[string]interface{}` into the desired structure after we've figured out what object type we have.

The complete test code I used here is included below; you can call `./example generate` to create `output.yaml`, or `./example parse somefile.yaml` to parse the YAML in `somefile.yaml`.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os"

  "github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure"
  "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

type (
  SnowfakeryConfig []interface{}

  SnowfakeryVersion struct {
    SnowfakeryVersion int `mapstructure:"snowfakery_version"`
  }

  ObjectSpec struct {
    Object string                 `mapstructure:"object,omitempty"`
    Count  int                    `mapstructure:"count,omitempty"`
    Fields map[string]interface{} `mapstructure:"fields,omitempty"`
  }

  FieldSpec struct {
    Fake         string        `mapstructure:"fake,omitempty"`
    RandomChoice RandomChoice  `mapstructure:"random_choice,omitempty"`
    RandomNumber *RandomNumber `mapstructure:"random_number,omitempty"`
    IfExpression IfExpression  `mapstructure:"if,omitempty"`
    Object       string        `mapstructure:"object,omitempty"`
  }

  RandomChoice []interface{}
  RandomNumber struct {
    Min int
    Max int
  }

  IfExpression []Choice

  Choice struct {
    Choice ChoiceSpec
  }

  ChoiceSpec struct {
    When string
    Pick interface{}
  }
)

func main() {
  config := SnowfakeryConfig{}

  if os.Args[1] == "parse" {
    version := SnowfakeryVersion{}
    objspec := ObjectSpec{}

    fd, err := os.ReadFile(os.Args[2])
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }

    if err := yaml.Unmarshal(fd, &config); err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }

    for _, item := range config {
      if _, ok := item.(map[string]interface{})["snowfakery_version"]; ok {
        fmt.Println("found version")
        if err := mapstructure.Decode(item, &version); err != nil {
          panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("version: %d\n", version.SnowfakeryVersion)
        continue
      }
      if _, ok := item.(map[string]interface{})["object"]; ok {
        fmt.Println("found object")
        if err := mapstructure.Decode(item, &objspec); err != nil {
          panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("object name: %s\n", objspec.Object)
        for k := range objspec.Fields {
          fmt.Printf("  field: %s\n", k)
        }
        continue
      }
    }
  } else if os.Args[1] == "generate" {
    config = append(config, SnowfakeryVersion{SnowfakeryVersion: 3})

    config = append(config, ObjectSpec{
      Object: "Logistics",
      Count:  1,
      Fields: map[string]interface{}{
        "Product_ID": FieldSpec{
          RandomChoice: RandomChoice{
            "M14860",
            "L47181",
            "L47182",
          },
        },
        "Type": FieldSpec{
          RandomChoice: RandomChoice{
            "A10",
            "C17",
            "F16",
          },
        },
        "Air_Temperature": FieldSpec{
          RandomNumber: &RandomNumber{
            Min: 298,
            Max: 300,
          },
        },
        "Tool Wear Fail": FieldSpec{
          IfExpression: IfExpression{
            Choice{
              Choice: ChoiceSpec{
                When: "${{Tool_Wear>2}}",
                Pick: FieldSpec{
                  RandomChoice: RandomChoice{
                    1,
                    0,
                  },
                },
              },
            },
            Choice{
              Choice: ChoiceSpec{
                When: "${{Tool_Wear<2}}",
                Pick: 2,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    })

    content, err := yaml.Marshal(config)
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }

    if err := os.WriteFile("output.yaml", content, 0666); err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: To use snowfakery the top two lines must be in list format. That is the part I have struggled most with to start. Do you know of any way to do that with structs

Comment: I see, it wasn't clear that this is an established format. I'll try to update the answer later today with some ideas.

Comment: I was able to figure out most of it but I did leave a comment with one more question on why it is auto sorting.